# Can not login another user with Facebook sdk for Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm using the Android Facebook SDK. I have written the code below to post pictures to the users timeline from my app. The problem is the pictures only upload to my Facebook account when I'm logged in and not to other user's accounts when they are logged in.

Why is this so? I get an error saying "photo upload problem. Error={HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Permissions error}"

```
 Session.openActiveSession(Image_UpLoad_Activity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

              // callback when session changes state
              @Override
              public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                  Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      if (user != null) {
                  //     TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                      //  welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "! " );
                          Log.d("", " USER THIS " + user.getName());

                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getName(), 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                      }
                    }
                  }).executeAsync();


                  Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(Image_UpLoad_Activity.this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions","manage_pages"));

                  session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
              request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),bmp, uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
                 Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); // <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT
                 parameters.putString("message",Dishname);
                 // add more params here 
                 request.setParameters(parameters);
                 request.executeAsync();

            //();


            ////     





                }
              }



            });
```

Comment: follow @Illegal Argument answer it's correct.

Comment: You should clear session after posting is done to prepare the way for the next user to use it

Comment: @Illegal Argument - i tried it, it doest work

Answer (score 2):

You are running your app in sandbox mode. You can make it available to all users by configuring your dashboard.

1. Open [developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/)
2. Select your app
3. Click on Status & Review
4. You will find a toggle button to do on/off your app from sandbox
   mode to production mode. By default it is in sandbox mode.